# What Flex Developers Ought To Know

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

What should know the Entry Level, Mid-level, Senior Developer? Theoretical knowledge, development tools, libraries etc. What issues are usually at the interview? Do I need to know Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object-oriented knowledge is a must. So good questions would be about:

- polymorphism
- inheritance
- encapsulation

Some main concepts that come to my mind:

- event handling, custom events
- invocation of server-side code
- collections
- exception handling, logging, debugging
- browser navigation support

About Java - Java knowledge is a plus on the object-oriented side, but Java experience made me expect Flex to be Java, which it isn't, and that might introduce some difficulties.

Comment: I would add to that: writing custom components in flex. If you really want to make it your every day job, working as good as possible is important. Also knowledge of the development environment would be a good question. (Eclipse or Flash/Flex builder) Setting up an eclipse environment for flex-development is a bit more work then just installing the Adobe flash/flex builder and how you code in it is diffirent. While flash/flex builder has an autocomplete function, this is (mostly) not in Eclipse.

Comment: i'd add: swf format restrictions, security sandboxes, and information from here: http://www.scribd.com/doc/913908/Flash-AS3-and-AVM2-Performance-Tuning

Answer (score 2):

in additional to Bozho's answer...

### At lower level

using source control

Basic skinning

### Mid level

Understanding of a framework (like Mate / Robotlegs) and a collection of design patterns

Writing code that conforms to various coding standards

more advanced skinning

Using modules / libraries

Garbage collection

### At higher level

Using the profiler to identify issues

Knowing when to ignore the design patterns

Being able to review others code at a high level.

Architectural design (What to actually put in those modules and libraries as well as maintaining them)

Flash Player internals

## In general

In general the further up the chain you get, the more theoretical knowledge and general knowledge you have. A senior developer *might* have more advanced coding skills (but not necessarily), but can bring to the table a wider breadth of abilities and experience. Especially knowing when to throw the rule book away.

It definitely varies from company to company, one might value hard core coding skills in their senior developers, while another may treasure softer skills, leadership, and reviewing talents.